# Query works in phpmyadmin but not in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I found similar questions but can't solve my problem yet. Here is the relevant code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM conceptos WHERE descripcion = '$descripcion'";
if ($result = mysql_query($query,$connection)){
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        //Do something
    } else {
        die($query);
        exit;
    }
} else {
    die(mysql_errno() . ' - ' . mysql_error());
    exit;
}
```

I don't have problems with the connection or the permissions, because this code snippet is inside a loop and the other queries enter the "Do something" section. But when I take the echoed query and execute it in phpMyAdmin, it returns 1 value as expected. Why? What reasons can lead to this behavior? Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Change `die($query);` to `die(mysql_error())` and see what it outputs.

Comment: Also note that the `mysql_` functions are deprecated, if you can, you should consider switching over to either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @AmalMurali mysql_errno() outputs 0 and mysql_error() outputs nothing. The query has no errors because it enters in the if part not the else part of the code. The problem is that the query returns no value and the same query (from the die) copy and pasted in myphpadmin gets one result!

Comment: If description is some variable text, then a) encodings might be messed up b) too much character escaping. Kind of example for (b): you could have `&amp;` or `&lt;` in you description, which become `&` and `<` after output in html.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko I think that the problem can be by the encodings... the $description variable has a single quote but I escaped it with mysql_real_escape_string() before constructing the $query string variable.

Comment: Where does the value of $descripcion variable come from?

Comment: @SergeSeredenko the variable is taken from a Excel file. But this file has about 1,000 rows, the query works for the first 778 rows, but in the row 779 the query found no rows but the descripcion exists in tha database as it is in the Excel file.

Comment: Ok, about escaping. Where do you echo it unless successful? If into html, try `die("!!!" . $query . "!!!");` then go into page source code and copy the query to phpmyadmin. There could be some more things you wouldn't see, like browser removes double spaces in your text etc.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko good tip!! After looking in the variable, it has extra spaces but not at the beginning or end of the string, but in the middle of the string. A remove extra spaces and it works!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and found that it was because I junked up my database by copy/pasting directly to the database from MS Word.  Pasting had inserted special slanted apostrophes that PHPMYADMIN could apparently parse but my php code could not.  Once I replaced those with a standard single quote, all was well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this "SELECT * FROM conceptos". If it's worked, you have bad query in "WHERE ..."

Comment: this same query executes about 1,000 times before (with the where part) the problem... the query itself has no errors, the problem is that it has no results but it must have. If the same query with the where part includes is executed in phpmyadmin it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your query is searching for the right description?  The double quotes should expand all internal variables, but you do have single quotes as well in case there is a copying to stackoverflow issue.

This will ensure that the description is expanded in case.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM conceptos WHERE descripcion = '" . $descripcion . "'";
```

Secondly, have you validated the variable contents you are using, as suggested by @crotos?

The mysql_ are also deprecated, so you should use PDO, or at the least, mysqli_.

Comment: I know about mysql_ deprected functions, but this is an old project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to setup the general query log of your mysql server and see what queries are really executed. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Also, check your encodings. Maybe your mysql connection is in ISO8859-1 and your table fields are in UTF-8 (or the opposite). Do you have any accents or special characters in your data?

Comment: ZeWaren maybe I must to reformulate the question, maybe the question is about how to make a query in PHP that works like in phpmyadmin, i.e what codification is used in phpmyadmin and in a php script. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

i also faced this problem and got it solved using:

```
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

instead of

```
mysql_query($query);
```

coz its depreciated

source:

[File Downloading error from database php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435936/file-downloading-error-from-database-php)