# File Downloading error from database php

Tags: php

I have read every tutorial I can find on this topic, but none of them helped fix my issue. I don't know why, but my code is just giving me an html file whenever I click on the download button, instead of downloading an image file.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="getfile.php?id=1">Download Now</a>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$id= $_GET['id'];
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
     {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Failed To connect to  MySQL: "+"mysqli_connect_error();"+"');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_files WHERE file_id = ".$id;
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
         $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
         echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('".$row_cnt."');</script>";
        if(!$result || !mysql_num_rows($result)){
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Invalid file chosen.');</script>";
            //echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >';
        //echo ' window.location.assign("ViewMyFiles.php");';
        //echo '</script>';
        mysqli_close($con);
            }
            $curr_file = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            $size = $curr_file['file_size'];
            $type = $curr_file['file_type'];
            $name = $curr_file['file_name'];
            $content = $curr_file['file_content'];

            header("Content-length: ".$size."");
            header("Content-type: ".$type."");
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
            readfile($content);
            $_SESSION['email']=$nemail;
            mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

I named the above PHP file `getfile.php` and I'm getting on download result as `getfile.htm`.

Comment: When you send headers, nothing should be sent from server to client before it. so in this case, I think this line:  
`echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('".$row_cnt."');</script>";` should be remarked.  
have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Debug!

Comment out the headers and see, what really gets to the client. Then comment them in and check in browser dev console (header + response).

You're also vulnerable to SQL injections.