# How do I re-order the output of a MySQL query with a GROUP BY AND ROLLUP?

Tags: mysql

Similar questions have been asked but none of them address my issue.

I have the following MySQL query,

```
foreach($db_found->query("
SELECT   netID
        ,activity
        ,YEAR(logdate)                   as Year
        ,DATE_FORMAT(logdate, '%M')      as Month
        ,WEEK(logdate,0)                 as Week
        ,DATE(logdate)                   as Date
        ,DATE_FORMAT(logdate, '%m')      as mnum
        ,COUNT( callsign )               as Logins
        ,COUNT( distinct callsign )      as Stations
        ,SEC_TO_TIME(sum(timeonduty))    as TOD
    FROM  NetLog
   WHERE netID <> 0
     AND logdate >= now()-interval 2 month
     AND activity NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
GROUP BY  Week,  netID WITH ROLLUP
") as $rpt { echo stuff here }
```

It produces exactly the output I need with one exception, the sort order. I would like to do an "order by Week DESC" but all I get is errors when I do this.
I've tried it with the 'order by' before the 'group by' and after. I've also tried the query using CUBE instead of ROLLUP.
All I want to do is list the same output but in reverse week order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your query in subquery like this and order.

```
Select * from (
    SELECT   netID
        ,activity
        ,YEAR(logdate)                   as Year
        ,DATE_FORMAT(logdate, '%M')      as Month
        ,WEEK(logdate,0)                 as Week
        ,DATE(logdate)                   as Date
        ,DATE_FORMAT(logdate, '%m')      as mnum
        ,COUNT( callsign )               as Logins
        ,COUNT( distinct callsign )      as Stations
        ,SEC_TO_TIME(sum(timeonduty))    as TOD
    FROM  NetLog
   WHERE netID <> 0
     AND logdate >= now()-interval 2 month
     AND activity NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
GROUP BY  Week,  netID WITH ROLLUP
) as t order by week desc;
```

Comment: I love how simple that sounded, but I got back an error.  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias' in /var/www/html/NCMreports.php:165 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/NCMreports.php(165): PDO->query('\n\t\t\t\t\tSELECT * ...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/NCMreports.php on line 165

Comment: Updated. Could you try again?

Comment: The problem may have to do with what I left off the query. I've added the foreach and as $rpt in my above query just in case that matters.

Comment: No that's not it. I added the alias it needs. Just try with the updated query pls?

Comment: Your example works perfect in phpMyAdmin but not in my PHP. Maybe it needs to be outside the foreach loop as a stand alone SQL?

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304351/query-works-in-phpmyadmin-but-not-in-php-script

Comment: I don't get an error at all just ... well nothing. No errors in inspect. Very confused about what I'm getting.

Comment: Got it! Forgot a close ')' now it works. You get the credit. Thanks.