# query can't retrieve results on script but works fine with phpmyadmin page

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a query that's working fine with phpmyadmin sql but not on a php script, it works but retrieves nothing

```
SELECT * 
from individuals 
where STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, '%d/%m/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('01/01/1984', '%d/%m/%Y') 
  && STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, '%d/%m/%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2002','%d/%m/%Y') 
  && (address LIKE '%جدة%' 
    || address LIKE '%جده%' 
    || address LIKE '%الطائف%' 
    || address LIKE '%مكة%' 
    || address LIKE '%مكه%'
    || address LIKE '%رابغ%') 
ORDER BY`individuals`.`birthdate` ASC
```

the connection and everything is fine, it works without the conditions just fine

Comment: I removed your PHP tag, as you haven't shown any PHP code. Show your actual code, or we can't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query works in phpmyadmin but not in PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304351/query-works-in-phpmyadmin-but-not-in-php-script)

Comment: Consider changing the data type of `birthdate` to a date/time type, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

`||` in SQL is concatination not `OR`!!! And also replace `&&` by `AND`

Change to

```
SELECT * 
from individuals 
where STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, '%d/%m/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('01/01/1984', '%d/%m/%Y') 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, '%d/%m/%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2002','%d/%m/%Y') 
  AND (address LIKE '%جدة%' 
    OR address LIKE '%جده%' 
    OR address LIKE '%الطائف%' 
    OR address LIKE '%مكة%' 
    OR address LIKE '%مكه%'
    OR address LIKE '%رابغ%') 
ORDER BY`individuals`.`birthdate` ASC
```

BTW: Change the datatype of birthdate to date

Comment: Yeah I know but it's just working fine in phpmyadmin, that's weird. I tried your changes but no results at all as well, same problem

Comment: I tried this query with only a single condition "SELECT * from individuals WHERE address LIKE '%رابغ%'". not working also

Comment: I'm sorry, data is sensitive and can't be seen by anyone. but to prove that the query is working fine I took a screenshot from phpmyadmin: https://i.ibb.co/1KchpKS/Screen-Shot-1440-05-23-at-9-02-09-AM.png

Comment: @user2373804 try my updated answer, you also have to replace && with AND

Comment: Tried the updated answer, same result, no row was retrieved at all

Comment: @user2373804 Looks like it is a Problem with your data-. But hatd to say without seeing it